# Increase speed by eleminating loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following problem. The code below successfully linear fits may data from 50 to 400 samples (I never have more than 400 samples and the first 50 are of horrendous quality). In the third dimension I will have the value of 7 and the fourth dimension can have values of up to 10000 therefore this loop "solution" would take alot of time. How can I not use a for loop and decrease my runtimes? Thank you for your help (I am pretty new to Python)

```
from sklearn.linear_model import TheilSenRegressor
import numpy as np
#ransac = linear_model.RANSACRegressor()
skip_v=50#number of values to be skipped
N=400
test_n=np.reshape(range(skip_v, N),(-1,1))
f_n=7
d4=np.shape(data)
a6=np.ones((f_n,d4[3]))
b6=np.ones((f_n,d4[3]))
for j in np.arange(d4[3]):
    for i in np.arange(f_n):
        theil = TheilSenRegressor(random_state=0).fit(test_n,np.log(data[skip_v:,3,i,j]))
        a6[i,j]=theil.coef_
        b6[i,j]=theil.intercept_
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiprocessing to work your loop in parallel. The following code is not working. It just demonstrates how to do it. It is only useful, if your numbers are really big. Otherwise, doing in sequential is faster.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import TheilSenRegressor
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import product

def worker_function(input_queue, output_queue, skip_v, test_n, data):
    for task in iter(input_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        i = task[0]
        j = task[1]
        theil = TheilSenRegressor(random_state=0).fit(test_n,np.log(data[skip_v:,3,i,j]))
        output_queue.put([i, j, theil])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # define data here 

    f_n = 7
    d4 = np.shape(data)
    skip_v = 50

    N=400
    test_n=np.reshape(range(skip_v, N),(-1,1))

    input_queue = mp.Queue()
    output_queue = mp.Queue()

    # here you create all combinations of j and i of your loop
    list1 = range(f_n)
    list2 = range(d4[3])
    list3 = [list1, list2]
    tasks = [p for p in product(*list3)]

    numProc = 4

    # start processes
    process = [mp.Process(target=worker_function,
                          args=(input_queue, output_queue,
                                skip_v, test_n, data)) for x in range(numProc)]

    for p in process:
       p.start()

    # queue tasks
    for i in tasks:
       input_queue.put(i)

    # signal workers to stop after tasks are all done
    for i in range(numProc):
       input_queue.put('STOP')

    # get the results
    for i in range(len(tasks)):
        res = output_queue.get(block=True) # wait for results
        a6[res[0], res[1]] = res[2].coef_
        b6[res[0], res[1]] = res[2].intercept_
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am struggeling to undertsand what you did. Why for instance is there an if statement and what will i need to do to get the code working.

Comment: The if-statement (if __name__) is required in Windows only. I didn't know what type of OS you use. Do get the code running, you need to define what `data` is as this was not given in your code example. Otherwise, I could have tested it.

Comment: I have a windows system. Data is an array of float 32 (400,6,7,350)

Comment: Then the code should work. As I don't have the data, I still can't run it. But I think from here you can solve it on your own.

Comment: I am getting the following error message: File "C:\Users\dorgerloh\untitled0.py", line 31, in worker_function for task in iter(input_queue.get(block=True), 'STOP'):TypeError: iter(v, w): v must be callable

Comment: Yeah, did get the same. I have edited the answer already. Just delete the "(block=True)".